# How many zeros are in all natural numbers from $1$ to $2019$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Problem :

How many zeros are in all natural numbers from $1$ to $2019$ ?

My attempt :

From $1$ to $100$ we have  $11$ zeros

Now from $101$ to $110$ we have $10$ zeros

So from $20$ zeros

Moreover from $101$ to $1000$ we have $201$   zeros

But its very tried I need simple method to calculated this zeros

Comment: I'd work it out for 1 up to 2000, and then count the rest by hand.

Comment: My answer would be none, because $0<1$.

Comment: Do left zeros like in $0012$  count?

Comment: How many times is the ones place a zero?  the tens place?

Answer (score 2):

First look at $1$ to $99$, than $100$ to $1000$, than $1000$ to $2000$ and than the last from $2000$ to $2019$.
We look at the different choices for a fixed digit to be zero.
Counting the choices is easier than counting all possibilities.

Start by looking at the numbers $1$ to $99$.
There are $9$ numbers that end with a $0$, namely $10,20,30,\dots,90$.
Because there are $9$ choices for the first digit.

Next look at all numbers from $100$ to $999$.
Here there are $90$ numbers that end with a $0$, namely $100, 110, 120,\dots,990$. 
Because there are $9$ choices for the first digit and $10$ choices for the second digit.
Next there are $90$ numbers that have a $0$ in the middle, these are $100, 101, 102,\dots,908,909$. Because $9$ choices for the first digit and $10$ choices for the last digit.

Next, look at the numbers from $1000$ to $2000$, there are $100$ numbers ending with a $0$, namely $1000,1010,\dots,1990$. 
Furthermore, there are $100$ numbers where the third digit is a $0$, namely $1000, 1001,\dots, 1909$. 
Lastly there are also $100$ numbers where the second digit is a $0$, these are $1000,1001,\dots,1099$.

Lastly we want to look at the numbers from $2000$ to $2019$. there are $20$ numbers where the second digit is a $0$, namely $2000,2001,\dots,2019$.
Furthermore there are $10$ numbers where the third digit is a zero, these are $2000, 2001,\dots,2009$, and lastly there are $2$ numbers where the last digit is a $0$, namely $2000, 2010$.

This results in $9+90+90+100+100+100+20+10+2 = 521$.
Counting the choices is easier than counting all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of *Wolfram Mathematica*, by brute force, we have:

```
Count[ToExpression@StringCases[ToString@Table[n, {n, 1, 2019}], DigitCharacter], 0]
```

> 521

while, reasoning a moment, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
n_{1,2019} 
& = n_{1,99} 
+ 9 \cdot n_{100,199} 
+ n_{1000,1099} 
+9 \cdot n_{1100,1199} 
+ n_{2000,2019} \\ 
& = 9 
+ 9 \cdot 20 
+ 120 
+ 9 \cdot 20 
+ 32 \\
& = 521\,.
\end{aligned}
$$